# SQL Request depending on a dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a small problem that's been annoying me for some hours now about a dropdown.
So, I have a dropdown which is filled thanks to a SQL request and now I want to get the selected answer to do another SQL request but I'm having troubles with that ... 
Here is my code.

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=PSF;charset=utf8','user','pass');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    echo 'poil';
    $choiceMicroscope = $bdd->query('select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema="PSF"');

?>
    <form method="POST" action="test3.php">
    <select name="Microscope">


    <?php

    while($choice = $choiceMicroscope->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $choice['table_name']; ?>"><?php echo $choice['table_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Send" name="Send">
    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['Microscope']) and isset($_POST['Send']))
        $nom=$_POST['Microscope'];
    else
        $nom="";

    //On vérifie si les champs sont vides
    if(empty($nom))
        echo '<font color = "red">The Microscope field should not be empty !</font>';
    else
    {
        echo $nom;
        echo "là";
        $test = $bdd->query('Select * from ".$nom." where ObjMagn="40x" and NumberBead = 2;');
        echo "prout";
        echo gettype($test);
        $test2 = $test->fetchAll();
        echo "ici";
        print_r($test2);
        echo $_POST['Microscope'];
    }
    ?>
```

When I test my request, I get

```
AxioObserverlàbool(false) proutboolean
```

which means that my request is not working ...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query isn't as you expect. You are using single quotes so the variable isn't being concatenated.

```
$test = $bdd->query('Select * from ' . $nom . ' where ObjMagn="40x" and NumberBead = 2;');
```

This also is still likely to fail.

1. Why give the user the ability to choose the table?
2. You also are open to SQL injections with this.
3. If the value is empty your default value is empty, which will make the query fail.

Comment: Ok so this request works ! Thank you very much ! I was sure I had tried this ...
1. Actually this is to build charts depending on the choice.
2. The database is on a NAS so only the people I work with will be able to use it.
3. Yeah, I know but I'm still working on that part ..

Comment: Ah, okay, then I guess well enough. Be careful if releasing to the public. Please mark this as the accepted answer when you are sure it has resolved your issues. Thanks

Comment: Yeah this dropdown is to chose from which table I need to select rows. I still have other things to see for my page to be complete.
The table names are actually multiple microscope names (or names used here where I work).

Comment: No worries, it will remain here and not be made public. Thanks again !

Comment: Would you know any way to make another dropdown menu depending on the choice here ? :s

Comment: You mean like sub-options. They choose one option then based on that are given other options related to the first? If so you'd have to use AJAX for that. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Yeah actually, the first menu select the table from my db and the second one should do a request based on the table selected.. I'll try AJAX but I've never used it ... Thanks for the link !